# angular2 view not populated until scroll in IE and iOS safari

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 app - beta13, with several views, services etc. It works just fine in chrome and firefox, although in IE11 and iPhone Safari browsers the page is stuck without populating the changes which are loaded onInit - until I scroll a bit with the mouse (or with touch scroll in iOS) and then it all shows on the screen like it should be.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Can you create a plunkr example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Unforunately its a complex page which is hard to plunker (lots of child components and services). I was wondering if anyone else encountered such behavior.

Comment: The solution for me, with a similar problem was to add styles dynamically with the syntax: [style.color]="dynamicallyAddedValue"

Comment: This might be related to this github issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6867